# How to remove ACL from a directory and back to usual access control?

Tags: permissions, acl

We use a hosting server of FreeBSD 10.3, where we don't have the authority to be a superuser. We use the server to run apache2 for web pages of our company.
The previous administrator of our web pages appeared to set an ACL permission to a directory, but we want to remove it. Let us say the directory is called `foobar`.

Now the result of `ls -al foobar` is as follows:

```
drwxrwxr-x+   2 myuser  another_user   512 Nov 20  2013 foobar
```

And the permission is as follows:

```
[myuser@hosting_server]$ getfacl foobar
# file: foobar/
# owner: myuser
# group: another_user
user::rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

Here we want to remove the ACL permission and the plus sign at the last of the permission list. Therefore, we did

```
setfacl -b foobar
```

It eliminated the special permission governed by the ACL, but didn't erase the plus sign`+`.

Our question is how can we erase the plus sign`+` in the permission list, shown by 'ls -al foobar'?

Comment: `getfacl` indicates not ACLs. However `ls` is showing a `+`. Are you sure you are looking at the same file each time? (this is usually the reason for me)

Comment: @richard yes, definitely the same file.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Our problem was resolved by using:

```
setfacl -bn foobar
```

The point was we also had to remove the aclMask from the directory with an option -n... The man page of `setfacl` says as follows:

```
 -n      Do not recalculate the permissions associated with the ACL mask
         entry.  This option is not applicable to NFSv4 ACLs.
```

We're not sure why this option worked, but it did...

---

In case you get `d?????????` permission after the above solution, try `chmod -R a+rX` as two commented below.

Comment: This made my files: `d?????????` that's odd

Comment: Update: This resolved it `chmod -R a+rX` the capital X

Comment: @JREAM What Linux system do you use?

Comment: I got that same d?????? thing with Ubuntu 16. Fixed with the above chmod. Weird.

Answer (score 16):

You should try using recursive option.

```
setfacl -R -b foobar
```

There is no need for -n option

Comment: -R is not supported on freebsd

Comment: @Peter -R is supported on FreeBSD since 12.0-RELEASE (year 2018).

Comment: OK i accept as answer, though then it amazes me some NAS products use such old versions of freebsd...   Oh i allread gave a solution.. just let hope at some day the software i used to work with gets updated to support this.

Comment: Works perfectly on Debian 11, no need for -n option or anything else